# php: issue with the select box

Tags: php, html

test5.php

```
<form action="test4.php" method="post">
Please input one package:(Goa, Kashmir, Rajasthan):<input type="text" name="package">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
<form>
```

test4.php

```
<label>Select Tour Package<span class="note">*</span>:</label>    
   <select name="package">  
    <option value="Goa" <?php ($_POST['package'] == "Goa")? "selected":"";?>>Goa</options>  
    <option value="Kashmir" <?php ($_POST['package'] == "Kashmir")? "selected":"";?>>Kashmir</options>  
    <option value="Rajasthan" <?php  ($_POST['package'] == "Rajasthan")? "selected":"";?>>Rajasthan</options>  
   </select>
```

I want to have this kind of function: when someone inputs one package on `test5.php`, the same package will be chosen/selected in select-box on `test4.php`, but it seems does not work, so what is wrong with the scripts above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to `echo` out the value as follows:

```
<option value="Goa" <?php echo ($_POST['package'] == "Goa")? "selected":"";?>>Goa</options>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is as simple as an `echo`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot `echo`.

```
<option value="Goa" <?php echo ($_POST['package'] == "Goa") ? "selected" : "" ?>>Goa</options>
```

For a simpler notation you can use `<?=`, that will print out result of any expression inside `<?= ?>`

```
    <option value="Goa" <?= ($_POST['package'] == "Goa") ? "selected" : "" ?>>Goa</options>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two things...

1. Enable error reporting during development.

   ```
   ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ```
2. Echo *selected*

   ```
   <?= isset($_POST['package']) && $_POST['package'] == 'Goa' ? 'selected' : '' ?>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

add echo in each option as

```
<?php echo ($_POST['package'] == "Goa")? "selected":"";?>
```

Answer (score 1):

also try with **trim($_POST['package'])** for remove spaces

```
<select name="package">  
        <option value="Goa" <?php if($_POST['package'] == "Goa") echo 'selected="selected"';?>>Goa</options>  
        <option value="Kashmir" <?php if($_POST['package'] == "Kashmir") echo 'selected="selected"';?>>Kashmir</options>  
        <option value="Rajasthan" <?php  if($_POST['package'] == "Rajasthan") echo 'selected="selected"';?>>Rajasthan</options>  
       </select>
```